# WP HTTP API call response

Tags: php, functions, api

I have the function in php but in wordpress the `HttpRequest` method does not work and I did not understand how to transmit the information with the wordpress functions.
My php function:

```
$request = new HttpRequest();
$request->setUrl('https:WEBSITE');
$request->setMethod(HTTP_METH_POST);
$request->setQueryData(array(
  'api_token' => 'APIKEY'
));
$request->setHeaders(array(
  'cache-control' => 'no-cache',
  'content-type' => 'application/json'
));
$request->setBody('JSON');
try {
  $response = $request->send();

  echo $response->getBody();
} catch (HttpException $ex) {
  echo $ex;
}
```

I have read that in WP mast use `wp_remote_post, wp_remote_get` and i try this:

```
$url = 'URL';
$args = array(
    'headers' => array( 'cache-control' => 'no-cache', 'content-type' => 'application/json', 'api_token' => 'APIKEY' ),
    'body' => '{"pass":{"serial_number":"123456","Name":"Michele","Date":"2017/11/11","Type":"Abb.Annuale","Issued":"Genn.2016","Al":"Dic.2018","Number":"0123456789412"}}',
);
$response = wp_remote_post( $url, $args );
$body = wp_remote_retrieve_body( $response );
```

But don't understand if my data is fine format.

Comment: `HttpRequest` isn't a standard PHP class or WordPress class. I can't tell you if your WordPress version is correct without knowing what you're trying to do.

Comment: I try to send a json code to a server and have an answer from the same I thought that my question was clear

Comment: Well your question didn't include the data you were trying to send, so I wasn't clear on what you were trying to do with `array('JSON')`. Have you tried this and it's not working?

Comment: I have update my attempt but think have wrong APIKEY location

Comment: Well that would depend on the API

Comment: ok thanks, do you know if i can put a variable in the json body?

Comment: $order='123456';
"serial_number":"'.$order.'"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This my solution:

```
$url = '##MYURL##?api_token=##APIKEY##';
$args = array(
    'headers' => array( '','cache-control' => 'no-cache', 'content-type' => 'application/json' ),
    'body' => '{"pass":{"serial_number":"123456","Name":"Michele","Date":"2017/11/11","Type":"Abb.Annuale","Issued":"Genn.2016","Al":"Dic.2018","Number":"0123456789412"}}',
);
$response = wp_remote_post( $url, $args );

$body = wp_remote_retrieve_body( $response );
var_dump($body);
```